# Check if a parameter exists in Django URL

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a URL if it exists in the URL but keep getting the following error:

> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'sc'

The case is that the urls can be sometimes like the following:

```
/allot-graph/
```

and sometimes:

```
/allot-graph/?sc='foo'
```

and in my function I am doing this:

```
class AllotmentbyMonth(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        q = request.GET['sc']

        if q:

            print("q", q)

            dataset = some query
        else:

            dataset = some query
```

Answer (score 0):

When a URL is like `/allot-graph/?sc='foo'`, you would use `q=request.GET.get('sc' , '')`.

sc is the parameter you want, and '' is the default value if sc isn't found.

Another way to proceed is to use URLconf, then your captures from the regex are passed to the function as arguments (or named arguments).

Such as:
`(r'^ allot-graph/(?P< sc >\w{0,50})/$', views.profile_page,)`

Then in your views.py you would have

```
def profile_page(request, sc):
    # Rest of the method
```

Comment: `request.GET.get('sc')` is enough.

Comment: `' sc '` won't work, but `'sc'` (without space) (seems like a typo)